# Php preg_match for french characters

Tags: php, for-loop, character, preg-match, diacritics

Can anyone help me to write a `preg_match` to validate alpha characters and french accented characters also? So far I came up with:

```
'/^[-[:alpha:]\'[:space:],_\/.]{2,30}$/ui'
```

Comment: Please clarify your question by indicating what is wrong with your current pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [unicode properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html):

```
preg_match("~[-\p{L}'\s,_/.]{2,30}$~u", $string, $matches);
```

Where `\p{L}` stands for any letter.